# como usar turtle con cordinadas y listas?

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa en python donde dibuje una figura en este caso un stickman y un cuadrado, en lugar de escribir todos los comandos quiero hacer que tome las cordenadas de una lista por ejemplo `stickman = [x,y,x,y,x,y]` y tome esas cordenadas de la lista y las dibuje pero estoy atascado, pobre hacerlo pero nadamas me permitia usar una cordenada, `stickman = [x,y]` alguien me puede ayudar por favor. 
aqui esta el codigo que tengo hasta ahora

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
t = Turtle()

def stickman():
        t.left(60)
        t.forward(50)
        t.right(120)
        t.forward(50)
        t.back(50)
        t.left(150)
        t.forward(50)
        t.right(85)
        t.circle(20)

def cuadrado():
        for i in [1,2,3,4]:
                t.forward(50)
                t.left(90)


def dibujar():
        t.penup()
        t.goto(100,200)
        t.pendown()


stickman()
dibujar()
cuadrado()
```

Comment: Dibujar rectas definiendo puntos es posible, de hecho también se pueden dibujar distintos polígonos, un triangulo son tres puntos, un cuadrado o rectángulo 4 y así.. ¿Pero un círculo? Si quieres expresar completamente el stickman, con puntos solamente no alcanza, debieras indicar además los movimientos. Por ejemplo algo así `('l',60), ('f',50), ('r',120) .....` lo cual debieras leer y convertir en `t.left(60);t.forward(50);t.right(120) ....`.

Comment: Entonses puedo quitar el circulo del stickman y en lugar podria poner un triangulo pero para expresar los puntos en una lista como puedo hacerlo? esa es la parte sonde estoy atascado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dibujar líneas a partir de puntos en un sistema de coordenadas `x, y` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *

t = Turtle()

def dibujar_linea(start, puntos):

    t.penup()
    t.goto(start)

    t.pendown()
    x, y = start

    for p in puntos:
        dx, dy = p
        t.goto(x + dx, y + dy)

    t.penup()

triangulo = [(100, 0), (50, 50), (0, 0)]
dibujar_linea(start=(100,100),puntos=triangulo)

cuadrado = [(50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 50), (0, 0)]
dibujar_linea(start=(200,200),puntos=cuadrado)
```

Algunos comentarios:

- La rutina `dibujar_linea` únicamente dibuja rectas, de un punto a otro de la lista que se pasa por parámetro.
- Se define una posición de comienzo `start` también como corrdenada `x, y` pero del lienzo o canvas. Desde esta posición se comenzará a dibujar las líneas y los puntos son relativos a este punto inicial.
- Mediante `for p in puntos` iteramos sobre la lista de puntos y vamos moviéndonos usando `goto`al siguiente punto de la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ah ayudado mucho pase mucho tiempo investigando pero no encontre nada al respecto, gracias de nuevo